# Bootstrap carousel image slider is not working in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

Code for bootstrap carousel image slider is working fine statically but same code is implemented dynamically in ajax success method previous and next buttons action is not working that means image is not sliding.

Working code (jsp & ajax) :

```
    <div id="textAreaId">
        <textarea id="writingPad" rows="13" class="form-control" placeholder="Start writing your note here..."></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="imageGallery" style="display: none;">
        <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li> 
                <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner"> 
                <div class="item active"> 
                    <div class="slide2"> 
                        <img src="<c:url value='/styles/images/2.png'/>"> 
                    </div> 
                </div> 
                <div class="item"> 
                    <div class="slide2"> 
                        <img src="<c:url value='/styles/images/2.png'/>"> 
                    </div> 
                </div> 
                <div class="item"> 
                    <div class="slide2"> 
                        <img src="<c:url value='/styles/images/2.png'/>"> 
                    </div> 
                </div> 
            </div>
            <div id="imageGalleryContents" class="">
            </div>
            <div id="imageNavigationControlDiv">
            </div>
            <a onclick="" href="#carousel" class="left carousel-control"  data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>
            <a onclick="" href="#carousel" class="right carousel-control"  data-slide="next"> 
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right">
                </span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>


success: function(data, status, xhr) 
{
    $('#textAreaId').hide();
    $('#imageGallery').show();
}
```

Not working code (jsp & ajax) :

```
<div id="textAreaId">
    <textarea id="writingPad" rows="13" class="form-control" placeholder="Start writing your note here..."></textarea>
</div>                      
<div id="imageGallery" style="display: none;">
    <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        </ol>
        <div id="imageGalleryContents" class="">
        </div>                          
        <a onclick="" href="#carousel" class="left carousel-control"  data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a onclick="" href="#carousel" class="right carousel-control"  data-slide="next"> 
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

success: function(data, status, xhr) 
{
    $('#textAreaId').hide();
    $('#imageGallery').show();
    var imageFileCount = data.length;
    var count = 0;
    console.log("imageFileCount ====> " +imageFileCount);
    for( var indx = 1 ; indx < imageFileCount ; indx++ ) {
        $("#carousel ol li:last").after('<li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="'+indx+'"></li>');  
    }
    imageDivData = "<div class='carousel-inner'>";
    $.each(data, function(index, value) 
    {
        console.log("index =====> "+index);
        $.each(value, function(key, imageData) {
            console.log("key =====> "+key);
            if(key=="imageFilePath") {
                var imagePath = imageData;
                count = count + 1;
                if (count == 0 || count == 1) {
                    imageDivData += "<div class='item active'>"; 
                    imageDivData += "<div class='slide2'>";
                    imageDivData += "<img src='/example/styles/images/4.png' style=''>";
                    imageDivData += "</div>";
                    imageDivData += "</div>";
                    count = count + 1;
                } else {
                    imageDivData += "<div class='item'>"; 
                    imageDivData += "<div class='slide2'>";
                    imageDivData += "<img src='/example/styles/images/4.png' style=''> "; 

                    imageDivData += "</div>";
                    imageDivData += "</div>";
                    count = count + 1;
                }
            }
        });
    });
    imageDivData += "</div>";
    $("#imageGalleryContents").html(imageDivData);
}
```

Comment: try  to add `$("#imageGallery").carousel();` at last in ajax success function. use id name which use for create carousel.

Comment: I gave the same id, but still it is not working.